# Idempotent completion of a particular category

Tags: category-theory

I work with a category in which every object $A$ is a finite copower of an object $x$, i.e. $A$ is of the form $$x\coprod x\coprod\cdots\coprod x.$$
Moreover, I know that this category has finite colimits. If I take its idempotent completion, do I get finite limits too?

I am almost sure I do, but I am a bit confused at the moment. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A category with finite colimits is already idempotent complete. Are you sure you've stated your requirements correctly? What examples do you have in mind other than, say, finite sets and finite-dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! It is idempotent complete? I didn't know that...Are you saying that my category is already finitely complete too? I don't have any examples in mind, I think I remember an exercise like this from my cat. theory course and I am trying to see what actually happens

Comment: No, I'm not saying that (I think it's probably false, although I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample). Idempotent complete means idempotents split, and splitting an idempotent is both a (finite) limit and colimit. This means any category which either has finite limits or finite colimits is automatically idempotent complete.